# React glamor doesn't solve prefixes in a correct way

Tags: css, reactjs, vendor-prefix

I'm new to React and I've recently started to use glamor instead of the various css pre-proccesors that are available. Anyway, I noticed that glamor (which should solve all prefixes) does not solve prefixes in the right way. For example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #fff 100%);
```

When glamor tries to add the prefixes, it adds

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #fff 100%);
```

Which is wrong, it should skip/replace "to bottom" with "top". The same thing goes with -moz- prefixes. My question is: why does it do this? Just curious.